# Present UIView modally that nots full screen

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios4, modal-dialog

I have a view 200 x 150 px which i would like to present on the tap of a button. If i use `addSubview:` then the view shows up in the correct position, but i can still tap other buttons on the superview, which is behaviour i don't want.

If i use `presentModalViewController` then the view takes up the whole screen, which is what i don't want either... this happens even if i set `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `NO`.

How can i present the view so that the user can only interact with controls on the presented view?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the view the size of the screen (taking the status bar into account). That view should have a translucent background color (or clear). Have the 200x150 view be on the bottom of that view to have the appearance of a UIActionSheet, where the background dims and the user cannot interact with other elements on the screen.

Then, you can use `presentModalViewController` to present the view.

**Addition**

In the view controller's .m file, define awakeFromNib:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Ive set the views background colour to clearColor but it shows up as white. Opaque is NO. How can i get it to be transparent? Thanks

Comment: Make sure to set the background color of the view controller's view.

Comment: In my View Controller i added your addition, but it made no difference. I had to use self.view.backgroundColor

Comment: It is still opaque white. I can change it to yellow and it works, so I cant understand it.